# Failed Loading Image with Picasso

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, picasso

I am trying to load profile image from **Firebase** user, by saving its URL to the **SharedPreferences** from the main activity and path its value to another activity which contain the ImageView i need to populate.

This is the code in **MainActivity**:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            isRegistered = true;
            if (user != null) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor userEditor = getSharedPreferences(USER_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                userEditor.putBoolean(REGISTERED, isRegistered);
                userEditor.putString(AccountActivity.USER_NAME_KEY, user.getDisplayName());
                userEditor.putString(AccountActivity.USER_EMAIL_KEY, user.getEmail());
                userEditor.putString(AccountActivity.USER_PHONE_NUMBER, user.getPhoneNumber());
                userEditor.putString(AccountActivity.USER_PHOTO_KEY, (user.getPhotoUrl().toString()));
                userEditor.apply();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the code i am getting in the **AccountActivity**

```
 if (preferences != null) {
        ImageView userImage = findViewById(R.id.user_image);
        String img_url = preferences.getString(USER_PHOTO_KEY, "");
        Picasso.with(this).load(img_url).into(userImage);
}
```

the Error message in the Log saying

> Picasso detected an unsupported OkHttp on the classpath.
>       To use OkHttp with this version of Picasso, you'll need:
>       1. com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.6.0 (or newer)
>       2. com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:1.6.0 (or newer)
>       Note that OkHttp 2.0.0+ is supported!

I included **Okhttp** dependency in my project.

Comment: It looks like there is an discrepansy with your version of `OkHttp`. You might want to add what you have imported in your `Build.gradle`.

Comment: thanks a lot, after looking in my Build.gradle i found me using an old version of Picasso, after upgrading it to 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' , now it works.